# Getting an error: "Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk'" on Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, compilation, xcode10

I am trying to create a brand new Swift project in Xcode 10.
But it is giving me build errors. This is the exact error that I get:

< unknown >:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneSimulator11.2.sdk'
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

[image: Swift compilation error Xcode 10]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happened when you had simultaneously installed several Xcode versions and after update you was left with only one last version. Solution is

remove the iPhoneOS11.2.sdk from that directories:

**Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs**

To-do list:

> 1. quit xcode
> 2. delete
> 3. clean
> 4. build project again